# Custom UIView delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and ios development. I am creating a `UIView` that consist of a `tableView` that I am going to use to display information for the user to select from similar to a picker but its a `tableView` and it takes up the whole screen.

```
class SelectView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SelectView", owner: self, options: nil)
        //contentView.frame = self.bounds
        //contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        print("cell ", String(indexPath.row))
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
        return cell
    }
}
```

then in another class that I have I am trying to do this

```
let pickerView = SelectView()
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.datasource = self
textfield.inputView = pickerView
```

This should work I think but and overwrite the default values that I have placed in the `SelectView`, but I am getting this error.

Value of type '`SelectView`' has no member '`delegate`' and Cannot assign to property: '`inputView`' is a get-only property.

Not Sure what is going on here, but it seems like I already delegated for safe measures and then just telling the class with the text field to delegate instead.

Comment: Do you mean tableView's delegate and dataSource?

Comment: I have a table view inside of the SelectView and I am trying to give it data inside a different class

Comment: @ukim I want to be able to have a class for a text field and then in that class do all the delegation for the table view inside of SelectView

Comment: You assign SelectView to pickerView.  When you do pickerView.delegate = self, you are trying to set the property delegate on SelectView, but you never defined a property delegate on SelectView.

Comment: obviously SelectView doesn't have any delegate and datasource properties then how can you set ? pickerView.tableView.delegate and pickerView.tableView.datasource and your other class must confirm to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl but I have a tableview inside the selectview class and shouldn't those delegates of table view be in select view

Comment: create your custom delegate

Comment: @karthikeyan Can I not just use TableView delegate?

Comment: By default UIView dont have any delegate and datasource like UITableview, What do you want to achieve from your custom SelectView?

Comment: I want to be able to click on a textfield and instead of a picker showing up I want the my select view to show up were the user can select from. The picker will not work because Most of the time I will have 40+ options and I want all the . realestate I can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Value of type 'SelectView' has no member 'delegate' and Cannot assign to property: 'inputView' is a get-only property.

The problem is that `SelectView` does not have these properties, the one who has them is the `tableView`, access to these properties can be delegated as follows

```
class SelectView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
        get { return tableView.delegate }
        set { tableView.delegate = newValue}

    }

    var datasource: UITableViewDataSource? {
        get { return tableView.dataSource }
        set { tableView.dataSource = newValue}
    }
   ....
}
```

use

```
    let pickerView = SelectView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
```

if you do not want it is also possible to access the table view directly

```
let pickerView = SelectView()
pickerView.tableView.delegate = self
pickerView.tableView.datasource = self
```

Comment: In practice what is a better way?

Comment: #1 encapsulate the properties, to restrict access to values

Comment: Otherwise I could end up with a code like that. `pickerView.object.other.foo.delegate`

Answer (score 1):

check this way,

```
import UIKit
public protocol menuOpen:  class {
    func openMenuAction(selectedValue : String)
}

class SelectView: UIView {
    open var delegate:menuOpen?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate.openMenuAction("test")
    }

}
```

Now in your another class

make sure confirm your protocol in your another class

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController,menuOpen{

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   let pickerView = SelectView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    textfield.inputView = pickerView
}


func openMenuAction(selectedValue : String) {
//get your selected value here, you would better pass parameter in this method
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting delegate and dataSource for tableView not the SelectView

```
pickerView.tableView.delegate = self
pickerView.tableView.datasource = self
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get value of type 'SelectView' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: @Dylan Did you try pickerView.tableView.delegate instead of pickerView.delegate

Comment: Yes I did and I got this value of type 'SelectView' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: @Dylan Please double check. You should NOT set delegate on SelectView, instead, you should set delegate on SelectView.tableView. If that still not work, clean the project and restart Xcode. Here's how to clean: cmd+alt+k